# PHP Best Practice to Update one record and delete another record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables ( voucher , voucherBalance ). My intention is to first to check whether if the voucher exist(assuming that the voucher exists), it'll be deleted from the table and update a record in another table.

Following approach is what im doing.

```
$voucherCode=$_REQUEST['voucherCode'];
$userID=$_REQUEST['userID'];

$voucherValue = $LINK->query("SELECT voucherValue from voucher WHERE voucherCode='$voucherCode';");
$LINK->query("DELETE FROM voucher WHERE voucherCode='$voucherCode';");
$result = $LINK->query("UPDATE userVoucherBalance SET voucherBalance=voucherBalance+'$intvoucherValue' WHERE userID='$userID';");
```

I would like to ask is there any better approaches to do this ?
Are that any best practice to do this ?

Comment: "Best practice" is a very unspecific qualifier. Please explain what concrete issue you want to solve, or how it misbehaves. Other than that, possibly might benefit from transactions.

Comment: @weechard you can directly update value no need to fetch value and then update. UPDATE userVoucherBalance SET voucherBalance=voucherBalance+voucherValue FROM voucher WHERE voucherCode='$voucherCode' AND userID='$userID'. this should be first and then delete statement. also do not forgot to use transaction.

Comment: The best practice in such a situation is not given by any order of execution - although semantically I would recommend doing the DELETE first. Take a look at SQL transactions. Start transaction, start deletion, start update, check for errors. If there are errors -> rollback. If not -> end transaction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: @mario Thanks for replying, my main concern is whether they way i wrote is correct or not, cause i felt like a mess whenever i look it =/

Comment: @androidavid Alright, will look at the link provided. Thanks for the help !